# continuous function from subspace $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: continuity

f:$\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that f(x)=a, for all x$\in\mathbb{R}$ is continuous function.

$\mathbb{Q}$  is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ and hence  f:$\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that f(x)=a, for all x$\in\mathbb{Q}$ is also continuous function with respect to subspace topology.

Using sequential continuity i can see that the function f:$\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that f(x)=a, for all x$\in\mathbb{Q}$ is continuous.

But if  i will think in this way , {a} is closed in  $\mathbb{R}$ and under continuous function  inverse image of closed set is closed   that is $f^{-1}$(a)=$\mathbb{Q}$ is closed. which is not possible because 
 $\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed subspace of  $\mathbb{R}$.   hence f:$\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that f(x)=a, for all x$\in\mathbb{Q}$ is not continuous.
where i am going wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [continuous function from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275855/continuous-function-from-mathbbq-to-mathbbr)

Answer (score 5):

However, $\Bbb Q$ is closed *in* $\Bbb Q$.

When analysing the continuity of a function $g:A\to B$, then you need to analyse, for any open / closed $U\subseteq B$, whether $f^{-1}(U)$ is open / closed *in $A$*. It doesn't matter whether $A$ is thought of as a subspace of some larger space; in this context that larger space *does not exist* for our intents and purposes.

So in our case, when we have a function $f:\Bbb Q\to \Bbb R$, you must forget that $\Bbb Q$ is a part of $\Bbb R$, and just look at $\Bbb Q$ as a topological space in its own right.